# MySQL - how to get count of a single item frequency in a table of CSV values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called "projects" with a single field containing CSV lists of project Ids. Assume that I cannot change the table structure.

I need a query that will allow me to quickly retrieve a count of rows that contain a particular project id, for example:

```
select count(*) from projects where '4' in (project_ids);
```

This returns just 1 result, which is incorrect (should be 3 results), but I think that it illustrates what I'm attempting to do.

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_ids` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `projects` (`project_ids`)
VALUES
    ('1,2,4'),
    ('1,2'),
    ('4'),
    ('4,5,2'),
    ('1,2,5');
```

I was hoping that there might be a simple mysql function that would achieve this so that I don't have to anything complex sql-wise.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!  Properly declare foreign key relationships!

Comment: For the sake of argument, assume that the model cannot be changed.

Comment: Whilst it can be done using a like condition, i agree with @GordonLinoff comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use this approach:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM projects
WHERE CONCAT(',', project_ids, ',') LIKE '%,4,%';
```

Or use `FIND_IN_SET` for a built-in way:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM projects
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('4', project_ids) > 0;
```

But, as to that which Gordon's comment alludes, a much better table design would be to have a junction table which relates a primary key in one table to all projects in another table.  That junction table, based off your sample data, would look like this:

```
PK | project_id
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 4
2  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 4
4  | 4
4  | 5
4  | 2
5  | 1
5  | 2
5  | 5
```

With this design, if you wanted to find the count of PK's having a `project_id` of 4, you would only need a much simpler (and sargable) query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM junction_table
WHERE project_id = 4;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any built-in mysql function that would achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, use `FIND_IN_SET` ... I will update my answer with that option.

Comment: Ah I see... select count(*) from projects where find_in_set('4', project_ids);

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a like condition as follows

```
select count(*) 
  from projects 
 where concat(',',project_ids,',') like '%,4,%';
```

Comment: Trust me, i didn plagiarize, i wrote the query the same time you have posted. The explanation follows. We look for pattern ',4,' and this is going to be compared with the values in the column project_id. To make up for the leading and trailing ',' the field is appended with ',' using the concat operator